# How to know which IndexPath.row is clicked on IBAction, and how to exclude a specific button from it being triggered

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController. It has one prototype cell, and spawns anywhere from 0 to 100 cells based on a user query. Once they load, I want an IBAction to trigger if a user taps anywhere within the cell EXCEPT for a specific button. I have multiple labels, and I still want the IBAction to be triggered if user taps on them. How do I accomplish this?

Here's my code for loading the tables:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TypeOfActivityTableViewCell
        cell.activityLabel?.text = activityNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.bgImage?.image = UIImage(named: activityPic[indexPath.row])
        cell.sloganLabel?.text = slogan[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

I do not want to code all this within tableView for MVC principles.

Comment: you can use tag value for this purpose

Comment: "EXCEPT for a specific button" - so you are having a `UIButton` and some `UILabel`s in the cell and want to trigger a specific action when the user taps anywhere in the cell except the on the button. Am I right??

Comment: Exactly mathews. The cells have "pretty" backgrounds, with text identifying what they are. I want the user to be able to tap them, and then an IBAction is called, but there is also a specific button inside the cell that should do something else. And I also need to know which cell index is tapped, because I have an array with specific values for each specific index that needs to be reached. For example, user taps the third cell, index 2, I need to have IBAction trigger, and then load mySpecialArray[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tapping anywhere in the cell you need not configure an IBAction. Just use the default UITableViewDelegate i.e:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
   let geoSearchWord = "geoSearchWord" + searchQuery[indexPath.row]
    let geoSearchLat = "&geoSearchWordLat=" + (lat == "" ? "33.9700" : lat)
    let geoSearchLon = "&geoSearchWordLon=" + (lat == "" ? "-118.4180" : lon)
    let geoSearchRadius = "&geoSearchWordRad=5mi"
    let twitterURLRequest: String = "https://quiet-cove-5048.herokuapp.com/tw?\(geoSearchWord)\(geoSearchLat)\                      (geoSearchLon)\(geoSearchRadius)"
    alamoRequest(twitterURLRequest)
}
```

Else if you have Buttons inside your cell for specific actions. You will have to add action to that button and assign a tag for identification(which button is tapped).

You can add action in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TypeOfActivityTableViewCell
    cell.activityLabel?.text = activityNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.bgImage?.image = UIImage(named: activityPic[indexPath.row])
    cell.sloganLabel?.text = slogan[indexPath.row]
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

Tapping on a button inside the cell will execute the below function:

```
func myAction(sender:UIButton){
   let selectedActivityName = activityNames[sender.tag]
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. I want to have a IBAction function, and within that function, code will run. But you are saying I should use the default func tableView(...)? Let's forget about the button for a second, how would I separate a function that "does stuff", for modularity, and have that function called on a cell tap?

Comment: I have given you both solutions above. You can execute an action using default table view delegate or an IBAction. You can separate your actions using indexPath.row in case of default delegate or sender.tag in case of a UIButton. 
If I misunderstood your question please elaborate a  bit?

Comment: No, it is I who am I confused. Your answer is great. Here is a jsfiddle with all my code. Let's forget about the button for a moment. I have my cells being loaded in func tableView with appropriate data. Depending on the cell being tapped, I want a function, ie functionX, to be called as so: functionX(indexPath.row). I am new to making apps, but so far my only two ways to have an action occur are either a segue or IBAction. I thought func tableView is simply to load the data. How would I call a function on a tap, and load the indexPath.row as an argument for that function?

Comment: The answer for this is already given but still let me know what you want to do in that particular function. I'll provide you the full code.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the specific function, and my current tableView: https://jsfiddle.net/rdeuxuwh/

Comment: Where are you getting the lat/long values in the "func quickSearch". Are you maintaining an array for these or they are globally declared?

Comment: At the moment, they are hardcoded, but I would eventually like to get that data from the user's current location using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: perfect then you need not pass lat/long as parameters to "func quickSearch". Instead use the code in the default delegate: I am updating the answer

Comment: You have no idea how truly thankful I am for your help.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this method works? so tableView, I thought, loads all the appropriate data into the cells. but in this case, it apparently loads them and then on a tap will call the search too? I don't follow

Comment: Yeah sure, If you are aware of delegates, it might be easy for you to understand. You assigned your current class as the delegate for the tableview. This means that your class can now control the tableview. All the default tableview delegate methods will not come into action until you have assigned a delegate for your tableview. So at the very first as your class is the delegate of the table view. The hierarchy begins:

1) The numberOf rowsAtIndexPath is called first.
2) Then the cell for row at indexpath
3) Tapping any of the cells will trigger the DidSelectRow delegate.

Comment: It's also working very funny. Only works on the first time the controller appears. Not everytime it loads again.

Comment: Just try to assign the delegate through storyboard. This might fix the issue.

Comment: so unfortunately what I thought would happen is happening. When the controller is selected, it immediately searches, without waiting for a tap. I have 3 cells viewed on the screen, and all three of them call this method

Comment: Can you share you class? I will check it on my machine?

Comment: How do I do that, share the entire .swift file? There's a bunch of pod files and stuff to make the API calls

Comment: You can email it to me. sidhuamrit321@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want click any where in cell then you can use its delegate methods

i.e

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

And if you want to add `UIControl` and on touch event of that control you need to do as follows:

First You need to add target for your control in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TypeOfActivityTableViewCell
        cell.activityLabel?.text = activityNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.bgImage?.image = UIImage(named: activityPic[indexPath.row])
        cell.sloganLabel?.text = slogan[indexPath.row]
        cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnClickAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
        return cell
}
```

Button Click fucntion:

```
func btnClickAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    var superView = sender.superview

    while superView?.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) == false
    {
        superView = superView?.superview
    }

    var cell = superView as! UITableViewCell
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)! as NSIndexPath
}
```

In above code you will find `indexPath`.

Comment: I already am using this, but I want to separate my code not to clutter it up. I am already using this method to build my cells. However, I need also an IBAction to identify the index of a tapped cell, outside of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one crafty solution.You can add an UIControl(e.g. UIButton) to receive touch in that special area.And then receive events in `UITableViewDelegate: tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`